# Setting a checkbox value via SOAP API

Tags: force.com, php

I'm trying to update a Checkbox field via the SOAP API (PHP) and I keep getting the error, "The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup."

```
$obj = new SObject();
$obj->type = "Membership_Option__c";
$obj->fields = array( "Cancelled__c", true );
$connection->update( array($obj) );
```

I've tried true, "true", "TRUE" and 1 and each give me the exact same error. Ideas?

Comment: Jason, I've expanded the answer based on your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to view the raw resulting Partner API SOAP call?

It should look something like:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:urn1="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <urn:SessionHeader>
         <urn:sessionId>00Do00000000001!AQ8AQI3Cp6CFl_NotARealSessionId_btbnffKopVHCzV9It0XeF.QL22amP7OeIXs1bjbcj9N</urn:sessionId>
      </urn:SessionHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:update>
         <urn:sObjects>
            <urn1:type>Membership_Option__c</urn1:type>
            <urn1:fieldsToNull></urn1:fieldsToNull>
            <urn1:Id>a01o00000000006</urn1:Id>
            <urn1:Cancelled__c>false</urn1:Cancelled__c>
         </urn:sObjects>
      </urn:update>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The raw value passed for the Cancelled__c field should be `true` / `false` at the SOAP level.

Note also that the `sObject` complexType doesn't have a fields collection. It uses a `any` element at the end of the sequence after type, fieldsToNull, and Id.

```
<!-- Dynamic sObject -->
<complexType name="sObject">
    <sequence>
        <element name="type"               type="xsd:string"/>
        <element name="fieldsToNull"       type="xsd:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <element name="Id"                 type="tns:ID" nillable="true" />
        <any namespace="##targetNamespace" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

So, while I'm not familiar with PHP, I suspect the problem is with how the sObject field is set. Also, you don't appear to be setting the Id of the record to update.

---

> Calling `$connection->getLastRequest()` results in

```
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns2:update>
<ns2:sObjects>
<ns1:type>Membership_Option__c</ns1:type>
     <ns1:fieldsToNull></ns1:fieldsToNull>
     <ns1:Id>a0G22000000QqPJEA0</ns1:Id>
     <0>Cancelled__c</0><1>true</1>
     </ns2:sObjects>
</ns2:update>
</SOAP-ENV:Body
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

> I chopped off the session id portion for berevity.

The `<0>Cancelled__c</0><1>true</1>` in the SOAP message appears to be the problem. Like it is converting the Array into XML elements.

Can you do something like:

```
$obj->Cancelled__c = true;
```

You want the last request to set the field like:

```
<urn1:Cancelled__c>true</urn1:Cancelled__c>
```